# exceeded flood-stage watermark but I have plenty of free storage space

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

The cluster is using one node and that is my own personal MacBook.

I tried on posting data to my index but I get the follwing:

```
"type": "cluster_block_exception",
                "reason": "index [english_minus_nouns] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];"
STATUS 429
```

I would understand from that that I need to allocate more space... but I have plenty though.

Here is my _cluster/allocation/explain

```
{
    "index": "english_minus_nouns",
    "shard": 0,
    "primary": false,
    "current_state": "unassigned",
    "unassigned_info": {
        "reason": "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
        "at": "2022-06-15T23:39:29.301Z",
        "last_allocation_status": "no_attempt"
    },
    "can_allocate": "no",
    "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
    "node_allocation_decisions": [
        {
            "node_id": "D3x06tGjTwmWSnZtCs2s0f",
            "node_name": "maemis-MacBook-Pro-9.local",
            "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9300",
            "node_attributes": {
                "shard_indexing_pressure_enabled": "true"
            },
            "node_decision": "no",
            "deciders": [
                {
                    "decider": "same_shard",
                    "decision": "NO",
                    "explanation": "a copy of this shard is already allocated to this node [[english_minus_nouns][0], node[D3x06tGjTwmWSnPtCs2s0g], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=k8wvFineTsKPH4vim2XLIP]]"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need anything else to help me let me know.

Here is my YAML file:

```
# ======================== OpenSearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: OpenSearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.opensearch.org
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: opensearch_homebrew
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /usr/local/var/lib/opensearch/
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /usr/local/var/log/opensearch/
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# OpenSearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of cluster-manager-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: Can you share your elasticsearch.yml ?

Comment: @Amit Of course! One second.

Comment: @Amit posted! :D

Comment: I don't see the `path.data` setting in your `.yml` so it will use the default one, check this post and find out which folder `opensearch` is using to store the data of your index, and if its in some partition which has low capacity, change the `path.data` folder to different location, and restart your Elasticsearch service, this should solve your issue.

Comment: @Amit I can see `path.data: /usr/local/var/lib/opensearch/`

Comment: Thanks for point this @Val, Xavi, please check if this `/usr/local/var/lib/opensearch/` path is not full

Comment: @Amit That is the thing... it is not full... this is running on the single internal drive in my mac and it has not been partitioned... I have space in my mac to even download a video game... Any command I should run on /usr/local/var/lib/opensearch maybe? Or another recommendation?

Comment: How much space do you have in your disk and how much is free? Try to run `df -h .` using the terminal inside the path `/usr/local/var/lib/opensearch`.